# Finding file name with variables in between

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regexp-replace, pentaho-data-integration

Having a hard time with Regex.
What would be the regex for finding a file name with variable in between them?
For eg:

File name : DON_2010_JOE_1222022.txt

In the above file name the words DON, JOE and the format .txt will remain constant. Rest numbers might change for every file. There could be characters as well instead of numbers in those two places.
What im looking for is basically something like `DON_*_JOE_*.txt` with * being whatever it could be.

Can someone please help me with this?

I tried `DON_*_JOE_*.txt` and obviously it did not work.

Comment: `DON_([0-9]+)_JOE_([0-9]+)\.txt` should work. Getting the values from these capture groups in java should be doable.

Comment: In Java, you can use `DON_\p{Alnum}+_JOE_\p{Alnum}+\.txt`. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/IJbzf1/1).

Comment: "*" matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

Comment: `DON_.{4}_JOE_.{7}\\.txt` will work. 
You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com) in future for regex related issues and do basic debuggig on your ow

Comment: DON_([0-9]+)_JOE_([0-9]+)\.txt Worked for me.. THanks a lot, f1sh(https://stackoverflow.com/users/214525/f1sh) for the comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript:
`"DON_2010_JOE_1222022.txt".match(/DON_.+_JOE_.+\.txt/)`

> whatever it could be

It is `.+` except new lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
DON_(?<firstString>.*)_JOE_(?<secondString>.*).txt
```

You can use this. To access the specific group, you can use `matcher.group("firstString")`.